# Calculate Hamming distance between two strings of binary digits in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hamming-distance

I have two equal length strings containing 1's and 0's. Each string is 128-bits long, and I want to calculate the Hamming distance between them. What's the best way I can go about doing this?

e.g. a='1000001' and b='1110001' --> dist=Hamming(a,b);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/pdist.html) with the `hamming` parameter.

Comment: Only thing to note is that this gives a fractional result, which is nonstandard.  You'll need to multiply the result by `length(a)`.

Comment: You also need to turn 1000001 into [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] in order to let pdist treat   each digit separately

Answer (score 5):

```
dist = sum(a ~= b);
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. Take dist = sum(4 ~= 8) produces 1, where in fact 0100 and 1000 have hamming distance 2.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: You missed that the OP has strings of bits, not integers.