# Matlab - How do I compare two strings letter by letter?

Tags: string, matlab, compare, vectorization

Essentially, I have two strings of equal length, let's say 'AGGTCT' and 'AGGCCT' for examples sake. I want to compare them position by position and get a readout of when they do not match. So here I would hope to get 1 out because there is only 1 position where they do not match at position 4. If anyone has ideas for the positional comparison code that would help me a lot to get started.

Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, I just want the number of mismatches out to apply it for another purpose.

Comment: Ok. Then Shai's answer is exactly what you want.

Comment: I am guessing by your question that you are dealing with DNA sequences that have only 4 chars - A,G,C,T. In this case I would highly recommend representing them as encoded arrays of doubles, and only converting to strings when you need to show them to the user. All of the operations that you need will become much faster and more convenient

Comment: Thanks. That's a good point, gives me something to look up next. I'm a bit new to all of this, so I always appreciate more pointers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following syntax to get the number of dissimilar characters for strings of equal size:

```
sum( str1 ~= str2 )
```

If you want to be case insensitive, use:

```
sum( lower(str1) ~= lower(str2) )
```

The expression `str1 ~= str2` performs char-by-char comparison of the two strings, yielding a logical vector of the same size as the strings, with `true` where they mismatch (using `~=`) and `false` where they match. To get your result simply sum the number of `true` values (mismatches).

**EDIT:** if you want to count the number of matching chars you can:

1. Use "equal to" `==` operator (instead of "not-equal to" `~=` operator):

   ```
   sum( str1 == str2 )
   ```
2. Subtract the number of mismatch, from the total number:

   ```
   numel(str1) - sum( str1 ~= str2 )
   ```

Comment: Yes, I just want the number of mismatches out to apply it for another purpose. Shai your code seems to work perfectly for what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Say you wanted to sum the 'falses' (matches), would you be able to insert something else in the middle of the two strings?

Comment: @user2180513 You should look at [relation operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html). You can compare using `==`

Comment: @user2180513 - If this answers your question, then please mark it as correct! (click the check mark)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare all the element of the string:

```
r = all(seq1 == seq2)
```

This will compare char by char and return true if all the element in the resulting array are true. If the strings can have different sizes you may want to compare the sizes first. An alternative is

```
r = any(seq1 ~= seq2)
```

Another solution is to use `strcmp`:

```
r = strcmp(seq1, seq2)
```

Comment: You should use the `strcmp()`, as it allows you to compare strings of different lengths. While `seq1 == seq2` assumes they have the same length. I.e. you cannot compare it like `'John' == 'Bob'`, but you can use `strcmp('John', 'Bob')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just would like to point out that you are asking to calculate the [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) (as you ask for alternatives - the article contains links to some). This is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178469/calculate-hamming-distance-between-two-strings-of-binary-digits-in-matlab). In short the builtin command [pdist](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/pdist.html) can do it.